# onEachFeature is not called

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers

I'm trying to add some markers with specific Style and Popups, but if I use the PointToLayer function, onEachFeature is not called. So I can't add popup.

If I use only onEachFeature, I can use `console.log(feature)` But I can't show markers. And if I use pointToLayer, onEachFeature is not called.

```
var json_chambre = L.geoJson(response, {

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        var markerCh = L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius: 5,
            fillColor: "#ff7800",
            color: "#000",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        });
        chambre_pit.addLayer(markerCh);
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        console.log(feature);
    }
});
```

There is no errors, just I can't have popups and style at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me quote from the [Leaflet reference for the `pointToLayer` callback option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#geojson-pointtolayer):

> A `Function` defining how GeoJSON points spawn Leaflet layers. It is internally called when data is added, passing the GeoJSON point feature and its `LatLng`. The default is to spawn a default `Marker`:
>
> ```
> function(geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
>     return L.marker(latlng);
> }
> ```

Notice what's different between that and your code? The `pointToLayer` callback **returns** the instance of `L.Marker`, and it gets added to the `L.GeoJson` instance (which is a subclass of `L.LayerGroup`).

Since you do not return the marker (or layer) instances, the `L.GeoJson` instance ends up empty, and `onEachFeature` loops through a grand total of zero feature+layer pairs.

Also note that you don't need to attach the popups at the `onEachFeature` step, i.e.:

```
var json_chambre = L.geoJson(response, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        var markerCh = L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius: 5,
            fillColor: "#ff7800",
            color: "#000",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        });
        markerCh.bindPopup(feature.properties.label); // Or whatever
        return markerCh; // And do return the marker so it gets added to json_chambre.
    }
});
```